# Reference parent pseudo selector with Sass.

Tags: sass

This here is what I want to do in plain CSS. Note that I only want to hover apply to the `.parent:hover` and not any parent with `:hover`.

```css
.container {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid 1px black; 
 }

.parent {
  position: relative; 
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em; 
  background-color: #4d4;
}

.child {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0; 
  top: 0;
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em; 
  background-color: red; 
  opacity: 0; 
  transition: opacity 0.5s linear; 
}

.parent:hover .child {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<div class = "container"> 
    <div class = "parent"> 
      <div class = "child"/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Question is how I do this in SCSS?

ie. if my SCSS is looking like:

```
.container {
    //... 
}

.parent {
   //... 

   .child {
      //..
      opacity: 0; 
      transition: opacity 0.5s linear; 

      //Hover selector here? 
   }
}
```

I've been playing around with [Sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/) but I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `.parent` selector:

```
.parent {
  position: relative; 
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em; 
  background-color: #4d4;

  &:hover {
    .child {
      opacity: 1.0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing - but I don't like that I have to define `.child` behaviour in two different places.